# While loop is overwriting head node of linked list in C

Tags: c

So I think what's happening is that my head node keeps being overwritten, but I'm not sure why.  If I remove the while loop and just put in something like this it works just fine.

```
head = addItem(head, "item one");
head = addBack(head, "item two");

print(head);
```

Here's the code as it is now, and underneath I'll include the header file with the functions.  Please note all my menu items aren't in the loop yet, have been stuck on getting the linked list right for a while now.  Thanks in advance for any tips or advice.

Main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "functions.h"

int menu();
void print(node *head);
node* addItem(node *head, char *item);
node* addBack(node *head, char *item);


int main()
{
    int selection;
    char *item;
    node* head = NULL;
    char junk;

    // Run the menu, and do something based on the selection
    do {
        selection = menu();
        // If they choose a number that's not between 1 and 3, or 0
        if (selection > 3) {
            printf("Please select a valid option\n");
        }
        // If they enter 1, add an item to the list
        else if (selection == 1) {
            printf("Enter your list item: ");
            // scanf leftover characters so fgets will work
            scanf("%c", &junk);
            fgets(item, 100, stdin);
            if (head == NULL) {
                head = addItem(head, item);
            }
            else if (head != NULL) {
                addBack(head, item);
            }
        }
        else if (selection == 3) {
            // Print remaining items
            print(head);
        }
    } while (selection != 0);

return 0;

}
```

Edit:  Forgot to add the functions in the header file.

```
    struct node
{
    char *item;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node node;


// Menu of choices, returns selection
int menu()
{
    int selection;

    printf("\nChoose an option:\n1: Enter a list item \
    \n2: Delete a list item\n3: Print remaining items \
    \n0: Quit\n\n");
    scanf("%d", &selection);

    return selection;
}

node* addItem(node *head, char *item)
{
    node *tmp;

    tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    tmp->item = item;
    tmp->next = head;
    head = tmp;


    return head;
}

node* addBack(node *head, char *item)
{

    node *tmp, *p;
    tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    tmp->item = item;
    p = head;
    while (p->next != NULL) {
        p = p->next;
    }
    p->next = tmp;
    tmp->next = NULL;

    return head;
}

void print(node* head)
{
    node *tmp;
    tmp = head; 
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        printf("Add an item first, list is empty\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    while(tmp != NULL) 
    {
        printf("%s\n ", tmp->item);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dumb question: what if selection == 2?

Answer (score 1):

You invoked *undefined behavior* by using a value of unintialized variable having automatic storage duration `item`, which is indeterminate.

Allocate enough buffer before reading input.

```
else if (selection == 1) {
    printf("Enter your list item: ");
    // scanf leftover characters so fgets will work
    scanf("%c", &junk);
    /* add from here */
    item = malloc(100);
    if (item == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        return 1;
    }
    /* add until here */
    fgets(item, 100, stdin);
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = addItem(head, item);
    }
    else if (head != NULL) {
        addBack(head, item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you MikeCAT.  Looks like I don't have enough rep to give you an upvote, sorry about that.  Thank you for explaining the reason as well, I'll be reading up on automatic storage now.

Comment: If `item` didn't have automatic storage duration, he'd still have undefined behaviour due to not allocating a buffer... only (relevant) difference if `item` had static storage duration would be that it'd be `NULL` initially instead of some unknown value.

Comment: And if `item` were not a pointer but an array with enough elements, saving pointer to the buffer in the nodes without allocating new buffer would result in seeing the string last read from all nodes.

Comment: So is the problem more related to the fact that I didn't have a buffer for `item` since fgets needs a buffer size?  Sorry for the newb question but I do want to understand what I'm doing if that counts for anything :)

Comment: @i_love_kittyz You need to allocate memory to read your input string into somehow, and it should be a different block of memory for each item in your list (either allocate a new buffer for each node you add, or use one buffer for reading input and then duplicate the string when you add a node so it has a distinct copy).  You had undefined behaviour by writing your input to some random memory location, *and* pointed all your list nodes to the same (invalid) string.

Comment: Ohhhhh ok, I was wondering why it was just printing out the last item I entered x number of times.  Thanks for the explanation!